# How to produce a jar file for existing maven project without (no main manifest attribute)?

Tags: java, maven, jar, manifest, noclassdeffounderror

I am new to Maven. I do not know anything about it.
I download an open source maven project form Github. 
I open it in Eclipse. I modified only one line to modified the pattern for date from this format:

```
final String pattern = "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p - %m%n";
```

To this

```
final String pattern = "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS} %-5p - %m%n";
```

Then, I tried to produce the jar file for the project.
The pom.xml that come with the downloaded project is using package shade plugin.

```
<plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${shade.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>shade</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <finalName>name-of-pro-${project.version}</finalName>
                                    <transformers>
                                        <transformer
                                            implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                            <mainClass>name.of.the.package.and.Mainclass</mainClass>
                                        </transformer>
                                        <transformer
                                            implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" />
                                    </transformers>
                                    <filters>
                                        <!-- This is necessary to avoid a java.lang.SecurityException -->
                                        <filter>
                                            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                            <excludes>
                                                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                            </excludes>
                                        </filter>
                                    </filters>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
```

So, I tried to get jar file from maven using this command:

```
mvn clean package
```

However, when I run the produced jar file using this command:

```
java -jar app-0.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I got the (no main manifest attribute) error.

```
no main manifest attribute, in app-0.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I searched for the MANIFEST.MF file to check for the attributes there, but I cloud not find it.

Cloud anyone help me if I missing some setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot just run a jar.

Either you need to specify the full classpath on the command line or you need to build the jar as `jar-with-dependencies` as e.g. described here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/574650/927493

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but in the pom.xml file that come with the project I have `<plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>${shade.version}</version>
      <executions>
       <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
         <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>` should I change this to the one in the link you provide?

Comment: The shade plugin is fine as well. I am not familiar with the different options.

Comment: Even with the shade plugin, it produce the same error it does not see the commandLine class that is in the picocli jar file.

Comment: It seems that it is not uses the pom.xml file because the name of the produced jar file id different from the one that is specified in the pom.xml file in `<finalName>`